# Storing multilple input items from Inputbox using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script that takes a .csv file and creates several hundred subdirectories on a network drive. In trying to put a GUI face on it I am having a problem. The dialog box asks for the .csv file and the path to the folder to create subdirectories. I assume that the line:

```
 {$Senior_Options_CSV = $objTextBox.Text;$Senior_Directory = $objTextBox1.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
```

is creating an array for the items in the dialog box but I'm not sure how to reference them in the code. Right now the script runs but I get no results obviously. The script is:

```powershell
<#Script to Create Directories from a .csv file. The script asks for where
the .csv file is located and then proceeds to check if it is empty,giving a warning if it is not, 
then creates a folder from user input with Student subdirectories.
#>

#From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx

#mainSection

  #Declare variables
[string]$Senior_Options_CSV 

   # Load needed libraries(Assemblies)
[void]  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Senior Options"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350,275) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$Senior_Options_CSV = $objTextBox.Text;$Senior_Directory = $objTextBox1.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(70,130)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$Senior_Options_CSV = $objTextBox.Text;$Senior_Directory = $objTextBox1.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,130)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9pt, style=Bold"
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the Location of the .csv file:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextBox.Name = 'Text1' 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 


$objLabel_1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel_1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,65) 
$objLabel_1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,30) 
$objLabel_1.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 9pt, style=Bold"
$objLabel_1.Text = "Please enter the Directory to create the Student Subdirectories(eg. S:\Students):"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel_1) 


$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Name = 'Text'
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox1) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()




#$Senior_Options_CSV = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the .csv file that contains `nSenior Options Students. The .csv file should include a 'First' and 'Last' column", "Senior", "C:\")




If ($Senior_Options_CSV -eq "")  {
       Break
     }

If (!(Test-Path -Path "$Senior_Options_CSV" -PathType Leaf))  {

      [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Attention. File Does Not Exist.`nCheck Your File Path and Name.","Warning", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
      Break

 }

#Create the array from the csv file selecting the columns you want in your array.
$Sen_Opt_Array = Import-Csv $Senior_Options_CSV | Select First, Last



#Check If Directory Empty.
  If (Test-Path -Path $Senior_Directory -PathType Container)  {
  $directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $Senior_Directory | Measure-Object
  #$directoryInfo.count returns the count of all of the files in the directory
  #Note.The 1 & 48 replace having to write out the [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OKCancel,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)
  #Portions of the [Windows.Forms.MessageBox] command
  If (!($directoryInfo.count -eq 0)) {
          $Dir_Check = [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Warning.The Directory is Not Empty! Do You Want To Continue?","Attention",1,48)
          $Dir_Check

        If (!($Dir_Check -eq "OK")) {
           Break
           }
}
}

for($i = 0; $i -le $Sen_Opt_Array.count -1; $i++) {
  $S_Name = $Sen_Opt_Array[$i]

  <#I need to force the evaluation of each value so I can display the data. To do this, I use a subexpression. 
  A subexpression consists of a dollar sign and a pair of parentheses.#>

  New-Item -Path $Senior_Directory\$($S_Name.Last)$($S_Name.First.Substring(0,1)) -ItemType Directory -Force

  }

[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$($Sen_Opt_Array.count) Files Created in $Senior_Directory Directory.","Attention", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
      Break
```

The odd part is I have this script that works fine with dialog box and four inputs:

```powershell
<#© 2014 
This program builds a form for users to input four parameters (screensavertimeout,monitor timeout,
hibernate off,sleep timeout) and changes these values system wide on the computer#>

#Load appropriate libraries
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 


<#Start by creating Form with properties you desire. See here for 
more information url:https://blogs.technet.com/b/stephap/archive/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form.aspx?Redirected=true#>

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$Form.Text = "© 2014"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650,375) 
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.Topmost = $True
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.Controls.Add($Label_Header)

#Create the OK and Cancel Buttons w/appropriate properties
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,280)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text='OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult='Ok'
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$Form.AcceptButton=$OKButton

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(155,280)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text ='Cancel'
$Form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
$Form.CancelButton=$CancelButton

#Create the label for the Form
$Label_Header = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label_Header.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif, 13pt, style=Bold"
$Label_Header.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,12)
$Label_Header.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(650,22)
$Label_Header.Name = "Power_Header"
$Label_Header.TabIndex = 4
$Label_Header.Text = "Change Your ScreenSaver and Power Saver Settings"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label_Header)

<# Now we create the four boxes ( three text, one checkbox) for the Form w/labels for each
   Font styles are: Regular, Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikeout 
   ex. $Label1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12.5,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Italic)#>

$Label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12.5)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,55) 
$Label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(380,20) 
$Label1.Text = "Change Power Off Display Value (In Minutes) :"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label1) 

$TextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.Name='Text1'
$TextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,80) 
$TextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,50) 
$Form.Controls.Add($TextBox1) 

$Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12.5)
$Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,110) 
$Label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,20) 
$Label2.Text = "Please enter Screensaver Timeout (Logout/In To Take Effect):"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label2) 

$TextBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TextBox2.Name='Text2'
$TextBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,130) 
$TextBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,50) 
$Form.Controls.Add($TextBox2) 

$Label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label3.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12.5)
$Label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,160) 
$Label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(680,20) 
$Label3.Text = "Change sleep time in minutes (Should be longer then Screen Saver timeout):"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label3) 

$TextBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TextBox3.Name='Text3'
$TextBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,180) 
$TextBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,50) 
$Form.Controls.Add($TextBox3) 

$Label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label4.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12.5)
$Label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(16,215) 
$Label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360,20) 
$Label4.Text = "Turnoff Hibernate:"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label4) 

$CheckBox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$CheckBox4.Name='$CheckBox4'
$CheckBox4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,220) 
$CheckBox4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,50)
$Form.Controls.Add($CheckBox4) 

#End of Form Textbox creation

<#  Check to see if OK button was clicked. If it was then execute the commands to change power settings 
by first checking for blanks or whitespaces#>

if($Form.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok' ){

    If ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TextBox1.Text)) {}
    Else {powercfg -Change -monitor-timeout-ac $TextBox1.Text}

    If ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TextBox2.Text)) {}
    Else {$TextBox2.Text = [int]$TextBox2.Text * 60
          reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /t REG_SZ /d $TextBox2.Text /f | Out-Null
          }

    If ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($TextBox3.Text)) {}
    Else {powercfg -Change -standby-timeout-ac $TextBox3.Text}

    If ($CheckBox4.Checked -eq $true) {powercfg -Hibernate Off}


}else{
       Exit
     }
```

I tried substituting in my new script but the OK button did not render??

Comment: Might be a scope issue but your first problem is that `$Senior_Options_CSV` is Null. You have a check for empty string `If ($Senior_Options_CSV -eq "") ` but this would cover both bases If (!$Senior_Options_CSV). Trying to figure out how to populate it. Also `$OKButton.Text = "OK"A` shouldnt have that trailing `A`. Guessing that is a type from the select all

Comment: I have the same issue running the code from the link you have as well.

Comment: Thanks that "A" was just a left over from an undo. The curious thing is this code from another script works fine with four inputs:

Answer (score 0):

**Forward**: I do not have a lot of experience with forms and this is more of a workaround than an answer.

For whatever reason the variable states are not persising outside of this code block. The [Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx) where this code comes from has the same issue where the `$x` in the sample is null/empty.

```
{$Senior_Options_CSV = $objTextBox.Text;$Senior_Directory = $objTextBox1.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
```

If you check on the return inside the same block with `Write-Host` you get the expected result. However outside that code block the variable is null. You can see this if you update your check

```
If (!$Senior_Options_CSV)  {
       Write-Warning "Senior_Options_CSV is null or empty"
       Break     
}
```

The way I tried to get around this was just to call the values of your text boxes. Since the objects still exist the values are still accessible.

```
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$Senior_Options_CSV = $objTextBox.Text
$Senior_Directory = $objTextBox1.Text
```

Code tested and work OK after that.

Adding a `[void]` in front of this line `[void](New-Item -Path $Senior_Directory...)` would suppress that output since you have a message at the end that tells you that information

Comment: Thanks Matt that worked.. I have to look at this closer and see why the scope is not working. i was curious what is the difference between the code in question and the second example I gave? I tried to give you an answer check but it says u need 15 reputation. Sorry

Comment: One other problem I notice. I put in a check for no input after the dialog box. I notice now though if I click cancel on the first dialog box the second dialog still pops up saying you didnt fill anything in. How get you stop this behavior?

Comment: Is the code you refer to already in the code you have in your example? If this is a different question you should make a new question. Also I missed writing it down but you should remove the lines in `Add_KeyDown` and `Add_Click` that change the variables as they are redundant in my answer

Comment: Yes. If I immediately hit cancel the script keeps running.I've only used the [Windows.Forms.MessageBox] forms and then checked for a cancel click and then break. This is not the case here. I'll have to look into it further.Thanks I removed those lines per your advise.